# invalid 'this' to a Java object in Nativescript Plugin

Tags: android, azure, typescript, nativescript

I am trying to develop a nativescript plugin to perform some functionality with the Azure SDK. The [docs](http://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-android-client/) for the SDK show below:

[image]

So I have added the following function to my plugin:

```
MobileServiceUser.newUser = function (userId, client) {
    var userObject = com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.authentication.MobileServiceUser(userId); // causing the error
    client.setCurrentUser(userObject);
};
```

UserId is a string.

However, the top line throws the [error](https://gist.github.com/georgeedwards/935a90d643f77fc11d56de0e4f065959):

> JS: Error: Trying to link invalid 'this' to a Java object

I have a full repo showing the minimal implimentation to create this issue on [Github](https://github.com/georgeedwards/Java_Issue).

I would be really grateful of any suggestions how to fix this.

Comment: did you find any solution for that?

Answer (score 6):

This answer is a little late but I recently ran into this issue myself. Hopefully this answer helps someone in the future!

The error is a bit plain but if you take a look at the code source, you'll see that it's actually telling you that you cannot link a variable to the Object/Class itself as a reference:

```
MobileServiceUser.newUser = function (userId, client) {
  var userObject = com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.authentication.MobileServiceUser(userId);
};
```

When you want to instantiate a class, you need to use the keyword `new` to signify this action. Without `new` listed before the class constructor call, the program just sees that you're making a direct link between `userObject` and the class itself. This should fix your problem:

```
var userObject = new com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.authentication.MobileServiceUser(userId);
```

Cheers
~Px